# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, mysql-workbench

Tengo el siguiente codigo PHP con una consulta que realizandola en MySQL Workbrench funciona bien

```
<?php 

    include '../conexion.php';
    $id_encuesta = $_GET['id_encuesta'];

    /* Consulta para extraer título y descripción de la encuesta*/
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM encuestas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $resultados3 = $con->query($query3);
    $row3 = $resultados3->fetch_assoc();

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/Logo-fis.png">


  <title>Resultados</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
     
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="color: #fff">
          
            <?php   
            session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_usuario'])) {
                  echo "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['u_usuario'] . "\t";

                  echo "<a href='../cerrar_sesion.php' class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left: 10px'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
                } else {
                  header("Location: ../index.php");
                }
           ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        
    <?php

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $resultados2 = $con->query($consulta);

     ?>

    <hr/>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1><?php echo $row3['titulo'] ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $row3['descripcion'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <hr/>

    <?php
        while ($row2 = $resultados2->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $id_pregunta = $row2['id_pregunta'];

        $query = "
        
        SET @suma = (SELECT 
        sum(usuarios.porcentaje_participacion) 
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = '$id_pregunta');
        

        SELECT 
        preguntas.id_pregunta, 
        encuestas.titulo,
        opciones.valor,
        resultados.id_usuario,
        usuarios.porcentaje_participacion,
        @suma,
        (usuarios.porcentaje_participacion*100)/ @suma as count
        FROM opciones 
        INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
        INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON resultados.id_usuario=usuarios.id_usuario
        INNER JOIN encuestas ON resultados.id_encuesta=encuestas.id_encuesta
        WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = '$id_pregunta'
        ORDER BY opciones.valor
                  
                  ";
        $resultados = $con->query($query);

                /*TITULO*/
        /*    echo "<h3>" . $row2['titulo'] . "</h3>";    */

        $cantidades = array();
        $titulos = array();
        $tamaño = array(); 
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cantidades[$i] = 0;
            $cantidades[$i] = $row['count'];
            $titulos[$i] = $row['valor'];
            $i++;
        }

        $opciones = $i - 1;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $opciones; $i++) {

        ?>

        <input type="hidden" class="<?php echo "valor$i" ?>" value="<?php echo $cantidades[$i] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="<?php echo "titulo$i" ?>" value="<?php echo $titulos[$i] ?>">

        <?php  
        }/*95*/

         ?>

        <input type="hidden" class="tamaño" value="<?php echo $opciones ?>">

        <div class="container" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;">       
            <canvas class="oilChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>

        <hr/>

        <script src="js/resultados.js">

        </script>


    <?php


    }
     ?>
    <div class="container text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <a href="reporte.php" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">GENERAR REPORTE</a>
        <!--
        <a href="reporte2.php?id_encuesta=<?php echo $id_encuesta ?>" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">GENERAR REPORTE2</a>
        -->
    </div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

el cual genera una grafica en base al resultado de la consulta ahi definida pero me genera el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda porfa no se porque me genera ese error

Comment: Tú estarías intentando ejecutar **más de una consulta mediante `query()`** lo cual no es posible. En ese caso, debes usar `multi_query()`, [revisa el Manual de PHP para más detalles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, he podido solucionar ingresando toda la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado y desde php solo mandandolo a llamar con CALL